# Is There Any Meaning To This Operator?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

A while ago I was thinking about how in physics there is velocity $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)$ being the gradient of a displacement-time function $x(t)$, and  angular velocity $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ being the gradient of an angular displacement-time function $\theta(t)$, and how in mathematics no one seems to define the gradient of the angle of a tangent line of some function at some point $x$. Perhaps this is for a reason as it might just not be that interesting, but I went ahead and came up with the following:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\mid_{x=x} = \tan\theta(x)$$
We define the operator $\hat{\theta}$ as
$$\hat{\theta}[f] = \frac{d}{dx}\arctan\left(\frac{df}{dx}\mid_{x=x}\right)$$
An interesting result is for example,
$$\hat{\theta}[\ln x] = \frac{d}{dx}\text{arccot}\,x$$
Which can be thought meaningfully as the rate of change with respect to $x$ of the angle of the tangent at a point of $\ln x$ is the gradient of $\text{arccot}\,x$. This is interesting but quite obvious if one were to calculate it. Another one is that
if $f'' = 1$ then
$$\text{arc length} = \int_a^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\hat{\theta}[f]}}$$
There are also interesting differential equations one could explore with
$$\hat{\theta}[y] = \frac{y''}{(y')^2+1}$$
Looking at invariants like
$$\hat{\theta}[y] = y$$
or perhaps
$$\hat{\theta}[y] = y'$$
These are for the most part the only interesting things I've been able to find regarding $\hat{\theta}$, and so I'm wondering if anyone can come up with anything interesting , or provide insights, or perhaps even reference a paper or something where this is used. Or perhaps if it is completely useless then one could say that too if they wanted.

Edit: To clarify, I know that there is a difference between a derivative and a gradient. The first section was just to explain where the idea came from

Comment: There is a difference between a derivative and a gradient. A derivative of a scalar-valued function is a row vector, while the gradient is the column vector with the same components (in an Euclidean context). The chain rule exists and gets frequently applied, as for instance if you insert the inverse function to $x(t)$ into $y(t)$ to get a function $y=f(x)$, or any other permutation of this setup.

Comment: I didn't mean for it to sound like they are the same. The beginning paragraph was just to explain briefly where the inspiration for the idea came from

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then it has a derivative $f'(x)$; the tangent at $(x, f(x))$ has slope $f'(x)$ and thus angle $\arctan(f'(x))$; it looks like if $f$ is twice differentiable at $x$ then your operator is $$\hat \theta(f)(x) = f''(x) \arctan'(f'(x)) = \frac {f''(x)} {1+f'(x)^2}$$ which is neither good nor bad, the only question is in what contexts can this be used?

Comment: The rate of change of the angle is *almost* the curvature of the curve. You have to replace $d/dx$ with $d/ds$, where $s$ is the arclength of the curve, in order to obtain a geometrically meaningful and well-studied notion. This is, in fact, $$\frac{f''(x)}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}}.$$